# Using fields from underlayer to populate fields

Tags: scapy

I'm looking at the CAN layers contrib and its [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/automotive.html)

I want to use the SignalPacket solution to implement a few messages described in DCB's but this raises a question. How can I easily make use of the CAN layer and then bind my custom SignalPacket based on the identifier field in the CAN layer, specifically how do I handle getting the 8 byte payload data that today is included in the data field of the CAN class, into my custom SignalPacket instance?

Alternatives:

1: Modify the CAN layer, removing the payload, then binding my custom SignalPacket to the CAN layer based on the identifier?

2: Leave the CAN layer untouched and in some way access the parent layer's data using pkt.underlayer to populate the custom SignalPacket?

**UPDATE:**

Answered my own question after finding a solution from the maintainers, see separate reply below

**Remaining question:** Has anyone used the #2 type of solution in any other case and care to describe how it would look?

Answer (score 0):

Polybassa has an answer to the question on the scapy github, proposing two alternatives #1 + a version of the existing solution with the CAN type and the custom type.

https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2252